# Numpy array: sequence too large

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of size `11` called 'wavelength' and a larger array of size `n` called 'MN'. And 'model' is an `m` by `n` array.

I'm doing this:

```
for i in xrange(10+len(wavelength)-2):
  y=np.empty(model[MN][i],float)
```

and getting this as an error:

```
  File "test_prog.py", line 658, in <module>
    y=np.empty(model[MN][i],float)
ValueError: sequence too large; must be smaller than 32
```

I'm not sure what to do about that. I've looked elsewhere online but I can't find anything of obvious substance.

Comment: Any reason you're throwing away so many values of `y`?

Comment: Oops, forgot that definition. See Edit.

Comment: Are you sure you're indexing `model` correctly? If `model` is _m_ x _n_ and `MN` is length _n_ then surely you want `model[:,MN]`?

Comment: Why are you trying to use the array `MN` as an index in the first place? This is a perfectly legal thing to do, but I suspect it's not the thing you actually want to do here if you're having this error.

Comment: To be honest I'm working with someone else's code that was handed to me. I'm trying to speed it up and got (above) as a suggestion, tried it, and it didn't work. That's why I threw it up here. The very first line was originally in the code and it worked as is, but it's REALLY slow so I'm trying to mess with the arrays to speed things up.

Comment: `sequence too large` error means that you are creating a multidimension array that the dimension is large that 32. For example: `np.empty([1]*33)` will this error. Are you sure you want to create >32 dimension array? If you want to create an empty array the same shape as `model[MN][i]`, you should use: `empty_like()`.

Comment: @HYRY this is the correct answer. Can you please post this as an answer so that people who encounter the same error can easily see it?

Comment: @HYRY you could post your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`sequence too large` error means that you are creating a multidimension array that has a dimension larger than 32. For example: `np.empty([1]*33)` will raise this error.

Are you sure you want to create >32 dimension array? If you want to create an empty array the same shape as `model[MN][i]`, you should use: `empty_like()`

Answer (score 0):

use:

```py
empty_like()
```

In your case it should be:

```py
y=np.empty_like(model[MN][i],float)
```