# How can I fix dimension i got the same error even i edit dtype with int32 or float32?

Tags: python, chainer

How can I fix this problem please?

```
dtype_attr = getattr(initializer, 'dtype', None)
if dtype is not None and dtype_attr is not None \
        and numpy.dtype(dtype) != numpy.dtype(dtype_attr):
    raise ValueError(
        'dtype mismatch: {} != {}'.format(dtype, dtype_attr))
if dtype is None:
    dtype = dtype_attr
dtype = chainer.get_dtype(dtype)
array = xp.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)   
initializer(array)
return array
```

Error:

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/chainer/initializers/**init**.py",
>   line 50, in generate_array
>       array = xp.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)    ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32

Comment: Please add some context. When do you get this problem? Do you run some code? If so, share it here

Comment: Include code or atleast the few lines where you're getting error.

Answer (score 0):

"sequence too large error means that you are creating a multidimension array that has a dimension larger than 32. For example: np.empty([1]*33) will raise this error."
as explained by the user [HYRT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772649/hyry) here: [Numpy array: sequence too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688094/numpy-array-sequence-too-large)